# Determining if the pde ($[w(x)u_x]_x -v(x)u_{tt} =0$) can be reduced to an ode using seperation of variables.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

So far I have:
$u(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$, $u_x(x,t)=f'(x)g(t)$, $u_{xx}(x,t)=f''(x)g(t)$, $u_t(x,t)=f(x)g'(t)$, $u_{tt}(x,t)=f(x)g''(t)$

$w(x)f''(x)g(t)-v(x)f(x)g''(t)=0$

$\implies w(x)f''(x)g(t)=v(x)f(x)g''(t)$

$\implies \frac{w(x)f''(x)}{v(x)f(x)}=\frac{g''(t)}{g(t)}$

I am not sure if I need to treat $w(x),v(x)$ as constants or where to go next. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $[w(x)f'(x)g(t)]_x\neq w(x)f''(x)g(t)$, unless $w(x)=$ constant. If that's not the case, your last equation should be $$\frac{[w(x)f'(x)]'}{v(x)f(x)}=\frac{g''(t)}{g(t)}.$$

Comment: Ah, this makes since. Thank you!